# Permission denied for Maven wrapper in CircleCI build

Tags: spring-boot, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-workflows, maven-wrapper

I was following a tutorial to setup CI pipeline for my GitHub repository with CircleCI. This is my `config.yml` file:

```
version: 2 # use CircleCI 2.0
jobs: 
  build: 
  
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
      
    steps: 
      - checkout
      - run: chmod +x mvnw ./mvnw clean install
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

> Error fetching your jobs
>
> #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail ./mvnw clean install /bin/bash: ./mvnw: Permission denied
>
> Exited with code exit status 126 CircleCI received exit code 126

Previously was using this command: `- run: ./mvnw clean install` but for both cases, I am getting same error.

I am a beginner in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used offline build dependency and now it works